# SFDX Listing Packages installed in Sandbox

Tags: salesforcedx, package

I wanted to check if it is possible to list all unlocked packages in my salesforce sandbox environment.

I can't seem to locate the command (if it does exist)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I figured it out:

sfdx force:package:installed:list -u